# Using node modules from fable

Tags: f#, babeljs, fable-f#

I'm trying to import a node module in my fable code. Being new to fable I did expect so problems and understanding the import flow seems to be one of those. I have the below code which compiles fine but fails run time with `Cannot read property 'request' of undefined` on the line of the `printfn` statement

```
module Session =
    let inline f (f: 'a->'b->'c->'d) = Func<_,_,_,_> f
    [<Import("default","request")>]
    type Http = 
    abstract request : string -> System.Func<obj,obj,obj,unit> -> unit
    let http : Http = failwith "js only"
    let start () = 

       http.request "http://dr.dk" (ff (fun error response body ->
           printfn "%A" body 
       ))
    do  
        start()
```

Comment: I don't know much about fable, but trying to call an instance method on null would seem like a bad idea - I think you need to give http a proper value

Comment: @JohnPalmer that line of code is taken from the fable example. The F# code is not executed it's cross compiled to JS

Comment: could you share the generate JavaScript code - I've found thats helpful in debugging

Comment: @Richard I no longer have the source code, let alone the transpilation output unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your example working in the [Fable REPL](https://fable.io/repl/):

```ml
open System
open Fable
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JS
open Fable.Core.JsInterop

type RequestCallback = Func<obj, obj, obj, unit>

type Request = Func<string, RequestCallback, unit>

[<ImportDefault("request")>]
let request : Request = jsNative

let start () = 
    request.Invoke("http://dr.dk", (fun error response body ->
        console.log("error", error)
        console.log("response", response)
        console.log("body", body)
    ))

start ()
```

And here is the JavaScript that it generated:

```js
import request from "request";
import { some } from "fable-library/Option.js";

export function start() {
    request("http://dr.dk", (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(some("error"), error);
        console.log(some("response"), response);
        console.log(some("body"), body);
    });
}

start();
```

Note that there are bindings for many modules already. For this particular task, I would suggest using [`Fable.Fetch`](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-fetch). If you want a library that works in the browser and .NET, try [`Fable.SimpleHttp`](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Fable.SimpleHttp).

Comment: Yeah the fable world looked somewhat different 5 years ago. There's been a tremendous catching up on the binding side since then